# Encrypting a whole disk

Tags: partitioning, encryption

If I have a HDD which is unformatted, that is all partitions deleted. Is it possible with Ubuntu to encrypt the entire thing is there some command/program that can do that for me?

I have a Netbook I wish to sell, but I want to securely wipe the disk and do a clean OS install first. So I figured I would see if I could encrypt all the data before doing a few passes with `shred`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shred is well suited to the task. Personally I would actually want to WRITE to the blocks rather than wrap the whole thing in encryption. Example,

https://serverfault.com/questions/6440/is-there-an-alternative-to-dev-urandom

Zap the disk with the openssl random data generator and then shred it. If you're really *that concerned* with the data that might be left on the disk then you should remove it and physically destroy. It's the only way to be sure as it's 100% under your control.

Comment: I am only really concerned because I do not remember what is on the disk since I haven't used the machine in about 10 months. I could have banking details on there. Then again my bank account isn't the healthiest so any efforts to get at the data would be largely fruitless, I suppose. :P Thanks!

Comment: @Luke: as you seem to be happy with the answer, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "1" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)